# Download a file involving Http Authentication from Scala code

Tags: java, scala

I have got to download a zip file from a server using HTTP Authentication in my Scala project.I have the following two questions.

1.) Is there any Scala or Java library that i can use for file download involving Http Authentication ?

2.) Also, any Scala library i can use for unzipping the folder ?

Please Help
Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) is able to handle [authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html). [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) can handle multiple zip formats.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use http dispatch (http://dispatch.databinder.net/About) which is a scala layer around HttpClient

2) To my knowledge there is no scala-specific api, but the java.util.zip.ZipFile provides a capable java-api you can use

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this but maybe you could just use java.net.URL and embed the username/password in the URL:

```
val url = new java.net.URL("http://username:password@www.example.net/zipfile")
val connection = url.openConnection()
```